# Github Actions - Change "Use Workflow" selection from default

Tags: reactjs, github, workflow, github-actions, pipeline

To make it simple, we're deploying our product via using Github Actions. Also we have a `develop` branch in which we're running some tests about our product. That's why, we're using `develop` branch as a default branch since we're opening our pull requests to `develop` branch automatically

Also we're running a manual workflow for going to production

But

I want to change the "Use Workflow from" branch for a specific workflow since it's showing develop as default in Production workflow

[image]

My question is, is there any way that I can show a different branch as default in this dropdown? I wanted to show master branch by default without changing the default branch of the project since this is the production workflow

Thank you all

Comment: The `Use workflow from` default branch is the same as repository. Therefore, (unfortunately) you won't be able to use a different branch as default there if `develop` is the one you choose for the repo.